# Adding onclick properties to each item in DOM object list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to move away from jQuery for my everyday site functionality, and I'm having a little bit of trouble with the `onclick` event. I'd like to put together a function like jQuery's `.click()`, but simply using `document.getElementsByTagName` and adding a func `onclick` won't work.

The question then is how would one add a single function to fire `onclick` to all elements in the list object returned by querying `document.getElementsByTagName('h4')`

EDIT: Just in case someone finds this and would like some code, here's what I did:

```
var headings = document.getElementsByTagName('h4')
    
for (var g in headings) {
    headings[g].onclick = function() {
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the list and pass the event to each item.
I think there is no simpler way to do this, expect you need a library like jQuery or you write your own eventManager...